# How to force the use of jack output every time on rooted phone

Tags: audio, headphone-jack

I have several phone A Xperia Pro a S4 mini duos (soon for sold) and a HTC desire Z.
I sometimes want to disable the speakers so the phone will only output the sound through the headset I plug on it, sometimes the physical detector does not work correctly or the headset is *not supported*.

What I want is a way to only output sound through the jack and only the jack.
Is there any mod ? trick ? modification of the android kernel ? an app ? that could do the trick ?

All my phones are rooted and unlocked flashing stuff is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [toggleheadset2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dwalkes.android.toggleheadset2). It's an app that has sorted that sort of problem for a lot of people. Hope that does the trick.